# MX Cloner : Clone results in undefined URL (404)

Tags: mx-cloner

MX Cloner running on EE 2.9.2 with Zenbu installed (also running Zenbu MX Cloner support extension)
When we select the clone option the site gives us a 404 page with the following structure

`http://www.domain.com/undefined&clone=y&use_autosave=n`

We've got this installed on another 2.9.2 site (also running Zenbu) and it's working fine - any ideas about where to look to resolve?

We've uninstalled and reinstalled both cloner extensions to no avail

Answer (score 1):

I've got the identical error, and I've also upgraded to EE 2.10.1. But disabling the Zenbu MX Cloner Support Extension doesn't work for me. I've also tried disabling and re-enabling MX Cloner.

What's the URL supposed to look like? It's as if MX Cloner isn't reading the Control Panel URL site setting.

**EDIT:** Max Lazar, the author, guided me to [the Github repository for the plugin](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx_cloner), where MX Cloner is up to 1.2.8 and resolves this issue when the extension is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have upgraded EE site to 2.10.1 and *disabled* the Zenbu MX Cloner support extension and this seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

EE 2.10.1 and MX Cloner 1.2.8 with Zenbu: still 404.
Solution: in acc.mx_cloner.php, find line 42. 
Replace:

```
 _href = $(this).children("td:first").next().children("a:first").attr("href")+"&clone=y&use_autosave=n";
```

with:

```
_href = $(this).children("td:first").nextAll().eq(1).children("a:first").attr("href")+"&clone=y&use_autosave=n";
```